# How to add glow effect In JavaFX custom progressbar

Tags: java, css, javafx, progress-bar

I have created a custom progress Bar in JavaFX. Now I want to add glow effect in the progressBar.

For this purpose, I have created an ellipse with gaussian blur effect and add the centerX of the ellipse into a timeline so that I can animate the glow effect in the progress bar.

This is the code creating the ellipse

```
public Ellipse glowshape;
DropShadow glowEffect;
SimpleDoubleProperty width;

//create ellipse for gloweffect
public void createEllipse(){

    glowshape = new Ellipse(25, 20, 10, 15);
    glowshape.setFill(Color.rgb(255,255,255,.7));
    glowshape.setEffect(new GaussianBlur(5));
}


public void init(){
    indetermination();
    setStartAnimation();
    createEllipse();

    width = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
   width.bind(this.widthProperty());
   setGlowAnimation();
}
```

This is the method for the animation

```
    public void setGlowAnimation(){

    KeyValue value = new KeyValue(glowshape.centerXProperty(),width.doubleValue(),Interpolator.EASE_OUT);

    KeyFrame keyframe1 = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(2000),value);

    glow_timeline = new Timeline();
    glow_timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    glow_timeline.setAutoReverse(true);
    glow_timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyframe1);
}
```

Though I have Bind the width property with the custom bar width property so the ellipse centerX doesn't exceed the current progress of the progress bar and should reverse back.But it doesn't happen when the animation starts it just moves a certain and then stuck.I think the Keyvalue's target value is not updating at all in the animation method.

It would be great if someone helps me on this.

Comment: Perhaps you could share a code snippet showing how you created the progress bar?

Answer (score 0):

> Here you are:

```
    //Create the ProgressBar
    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();

    //Create a drop shadow effect
    DropShadow glowEffect= new DropShadow();
    glowEffect.setOffsetY(0f);
    glowEffect.setOffsetX(0f);
    glowEffect.setColor(Color.RED);
    glowEffect.setWidth(depth);
    glowEffect.setHeight(depth);

    progressBar.setEffect(glowEffect); //Apply the glowEffecteffect to the JavaFX ProgressBar
```

> Mention that:

1)To change the width/height of the `glowEffect` you can modify `setWidth(..);` and `setHeight();`.Mention that methods `setOffSetX(0);` `setOffSetY(0f);` are used to center the `glowEffect`.

2)The procedure is the same for the `costum progressBar` as it extends `Node` class.

> Also i add this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/effect/Glow.html) in case you need something like:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi,
I have tried your code but It didn't work.Drop shadow creates an effect outside of the node.

However,I have created an Ellipse with gaussian blur effect and then start an animation to animate the glow effect throughout the progress bar during progress.I also bind the key values target value with the progress bar's width property.But it is not working also.It just moves a little bit and stuck. The target value doesn't update.I don't understand why it's happening.Can you help me on this